# Cannot import package in AWS lambda with Nodejs14.x ES module

Tags: aws-lambda, esmodules, node-js-14

I have a layer where the path of node_modules is `nodejs/node14/node_modules`.

Using that layer, and I try to import a package in a Lambda function, say 'aws-cloudfront-sign', like this:

```
import cfsign from 'aws-cloudfront-sign'
```

I got error message

```
Cannot find package 'aws-cloudfront-sign' imported from /var/task/signer.js\nDid you mean to import aws-cloudfront-sign/lib/cloudfrontUtil.js?
```

But if I import the package like this:

```
import cfsign from '/opt/nodejs/node14/node_modules/aws-cloudfront-sign/lib/cloudfrontUtil.js'
```

It succeeds.

Do you know why? How could I import the package correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**2023 Update:**

Note that the solution below was for a Node 14 problem with a specific SDK version, per the question. **Imports for AWS SDK v3 are now supported in Node 18+**. Using the below solution for other Node/SDK versions likely will not work.

See the [AWS post here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3230#issuecomment-1561973247) and the discussion [ESM imports from NODE_PATH are not available when using Lambda's Node Runtime 14 and 16](https://github.com/vibe/aws-esm-modules-layer-support).

**End update**

---

This appears to be a bug. It is occurring with layers and the SDK. There are are a number of similar open issues on Github:

[Nodejs Lambda: Cannot find package 'aws-sdk'](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3230)

[Cannot find package when using ES Module and Lambda Layer](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3386)

[ES6 imports don't work in @aws-sdk/client-iotsitewise](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3578)

As you have worked out, the only workaround at present seems to be the use of absolute paths. E.g.:

```
import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk;'
```

fails, whereas

```
import AWS from '/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/aws.js';
const { DynamoDB } = AWS;
```

will work.

I suggest you add your voice to an existing open issue to help ensure it gets attention.

Comment: Thank you! I have opened a ticket to ask about this. Hope they fix it soon.

Comment: I have also run into this issue, the above solution just gave me this error: 
"errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/aws.js' imported from /var/task/index.mjs",

Comment: `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/aws.js' imported from /var/task/index.mjs`

Comment: The 2023 update section helped me. I was upgrading from node 16.x to 18.x runtime for it to work.

Comment: What I didn't get is that in `v3` they split the sdk to help with build size, so you will need to import based on the service you use. Use the docs:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/introduction/

Answer (score 2):

I was running across a similar issue. I wasn't able to import my Dynomdb in my lambda function.

I ended up doing something like this.

```
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import {
  DynamoDBDocumentClient,
  PutCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});

const dynamo = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);
```

This will create a new client that you can use to run the various commands.

See documentation here: [AWS SDK for JavaScript DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/)

Check out these Client Documentation for DynamoDB [enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/classes/dynamodbclient.html)